# Changing the Variable of Integration with Product of Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

I am a bit confused about how to tackle the following integration and was hoping to find some help here.

## Problem

I have an integral of the following form
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_f}\! f(a(x),y)\cdot j_l\left(y\left(x_f-x\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $j_l$ is a spherical Bessel function.

Now, I'd like to re-express the whole integral depending on the variable $a(x)$ with
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}a}=\frac{1}{a^2g(a)},
$$

assuming that the function $f(a(x))$ and $g(a)$ are known as well as the limits of the integration $a(x_f)=1$ and $a(x_i)=0$.

## Question

How can I get rid of the $x$-dependence and re-express this as an integral over $a$? So, mainly, what do I have to do with the spherical Bessel function?

## Attempt

I see that the argument in the Bessel function, $x_f-x$ can be expressed as $\int_{a(x)}^{a(x_f)}\!\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{a^2g(a)}$, but I think the result is not just

$$
\int_{a(x_i)}^{a(x_f)}\! f(a,y)\cdot j_l\left(y\left(\int_{a(x)}^{a(x_f)}\!\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{a^2g(a)}\right)\right)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{a^2g(a)},
$$
but that there should be an additional factor or dependence arising from the change of variable in the Bessel function, but I cannot wrap my head around what it should be.

If you'd spot what it is, you'd be my personal hero of the day. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d a}(a) =\dfrac 1{a^2\,g(a)}$ entails that $x(a) = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\mathrm d a}{a^2~g(a)}~+C$, where $x$ is a function of $a$, and $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

So the term you want is this:

$$x_f-x(a) = x_f-\int\dfrac{\mathrm d a}{a^2~g(a)}-C$$